# Date is not changing

Tags: xml, date, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<request>
  <event>
    <st1>ky</st1>
    <st2>de</st2>
    <st3></st3>
    <st4></st4>
    <st5></st5>
    <starttime>2011-11-01T00:00:00</starttime>
    <endtime></endtime>
    <ty>
      <st_in>
        <stno>1</stno>
        <stid></stid>
      </st_in>
    </ty>
    <mt_in>
      <mt_mem>
        <mt_id></mt_id>
        <mt_1></mt_1>
      </mt_mem>
    </mt_in>
</request>
```

If there is empty I want to update it to some default value of NO except for elements ty and mt_in and starttime and endtime.

So the output will be

```
<request>
  <event>
    <st1>ky</st1>
    <st2>de</st2>
    <st3>NO</st3>
    <st4>NO</st4>
    <st5>NO</st5>
    <starttime>>01-Nov-2011 12:00:00 AM</starttime>
    <endtime>NULL</endtime>
    <ty>
      <st_in>
        <stno>1</stno>
        <stid></stid>
      </st_in>
    </ty>
    <mt_in>
      <mt_mem>
        <mt_id></mt_id>
        <mt_1></mt_1>
      </mt_mem>
    </mt_in>
  </event>
</request>
```

Stylesheet used is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:date="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="date" exclude-result-prefixes="">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="starttime|endtime">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not(normalize-space(string(.))) = ''">
                <xsl:variable name="inpdate" select="string(.)"/>
                <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="date:format-date($inpdate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss a')"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'NULL'"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(node()) and not(ancestor-or-self::*[self::ty|self::mt_in|self::starttime|self::endtime])]">
        <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="'+'"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

got everyhting working but the if date is present it is not changing the format to 01-Nov-2011 12:00:00 AM. what mistake i did

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: IBM  datapower SOA appliance

Comment: Are you sure it supports the date:format-date() extension function?

Comment: DataPower does support EXSLT date:format-date().  What result are you getting?

Comment: if i put everything in single stylesheet date is not changing to the format i want. if i have another stylesheet with that template again then it is changing